Getting error ORA-29273 - "HTTP request failed" when tried to make an utl_http.request in oracle sql developer
Here is what I'm trying to do:
SELECT utl_http.request('openexchangerates.org',NULL,'file:C:/Users/Uchih/OneDrive/Escritorio/wallet','password123') from dual;

I need to make a http.request, to test a connection to that web site to use a webservice from that page.
And also I already have configured my wallet with all the certificates of the web page.
So the wallet shouldn't be a problem
And here is my acl code:
BEGIN

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
    acl => 'otro_acl.xml',
    description => 'otra prueba',
    principal   => 'APEX_220200',
    is_grant    =>  TRUE,
    privilege   => 'connect'
);


END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
        acl => 'otro_acl.xml',
        principal   => 'APEX_220200',
        is_grant    => TRUE,
        privilege   => 'resolve'
    );

END;


BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
        acl =>  'otro_acl.xml',
        host    => 'openexchangerates.org',
        lower_port  => NULL,
        upper_port  => NULL
    );

END;

Also I assigned te privileges to my hr user:
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
        acl => 'otro_acl.xml',
        principal   => 'HR',
        is_grant    => TRUE,
        privilege   => 'connect'
    );

END;




BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
        acl => 'otro_acl.xml',
        principal   => 'HR',
        is_grant    => TRUE,
        privilege   => 'resolve'
    );

END;

But I'm getting these errors:
ORA-29273: fallo de la solicitud HTTP
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 1530
ORA-28759: fallo al abrir el archivo
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 651
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 1472
ORA-06512: en línea 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.


Did you try URL, i.e. with https://?

The error states "Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message." Did you do that? What was the output?


I need to make a http.request, to test a connection to that web site to use a webservice from that page.

It's not quite clear do you want to just test connection to the web site (availability) or you want to make a test connection to a specific webservice at the site. Since there are no informations about webservice/API all we can do is test the url connection to 'openexchangerates.org' using UTL_HTTP.
Here is the procedure used for testing:
create or replace procedure "TEST_REQUEST"
is
BEGIN
    Declare
        v_body      CLOB := empty_clob();
        v_buffer    VarChar2(32767);
        --
        mReq        UTL_HTTP.req;
        mResp       UTL_HTTP.resp;
        v_url       VarChar2(128) := 'openexchangerates.org';  
    Begin
        UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
        UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (30);

        mReq := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(v_url, 'POST');
        
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-type', 'application/json');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-Length', length(v_body));
        
        UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(mReq, v_body);

        mResp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(mReq);

        begin
            loop
                utl_http.read_line(mResp, v_buffer);
                dbms_output.put_line(v_buffer);
            end loop;
            utl_http.end_response(mResp);
        exception
            when utl_http.end_of_body then
                utl_http.end_response(mResp);
        end;

    Exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm);
            utl_http.end_response(mResp);
    End;
END;

... doing the test ...
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    TEST_REQUEST;
END;
/

/*    R e s u l t :
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://openexchangerates.org/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at openexchangerates.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
*/

So, the utl_http request was sent to your url, connection was established and response was received.
Regarding unknown webservice/API can't tell anything, but maybe some guidence you could get within the answer to issues  similar to this. Check it HERE - along with code example.
